# Big-O time complexity, nested for and while loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to understand Big-O Time complexity and am unfortunately struggling, I cannot seem to grasp the concept, I know my results are correct for the following two code fragments however how I got there seems to be wrong. Would someone be able to help explain where I'm mis-understanding (not please, however not using sigma. Thank you!

```
Code Fragment               Time Complexity
sum ← 0                     O(1)
  for i ← 1 to n do         O(n)
    for j ← 1 to n do       O(n)
      k←1                   O(1)
      while k < n do        
        k ← k * C           O(log n)  - affected by C (due to multiplication)
        sum ← sum + 1       O(1)
                            -----------
                            O(1 x n x n x 1 x [log n] x 1)
                            O(n2 log n)

Code Fragment             Time Complexity
sum ← 0                   O(1)
 for i ← 1 to n do        O(n)
  for j ← 1 to i do       O(n) 
    k←1                   O(1)
    while k < n do      
      k ← k + C           O(n) – not affected by C, k is arbitrarily large
      sum ← sum + 1       O(1)
                            -----------
                          O(1 x n x n x 1 x n x 1)
                          O(n^3)
```

Comment: Which step don't you understand?

Comment: Also, how is this related to Java?

Comment: I think there is one thing where your time complexity is off, and that is the O(log n) for k * C. It's rather that the loop above runs that many times due to this multiplication of the loop variable. Similarly in the second piece of code. For comparison, you also have a single complexity assigned to the for-loops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see minor errors in the computation, though the final results are correct.

In the first algorithm :

```
O(1 x n x n x 1 x [log n] x 1)
```

should be

```
1 + n x n x (1 + (O(log n) x 2)) = O(n^2 * log n)
```

In the second algorithm :

```
O(1 x n x n x 1 x n x 1)
```

should be

```
1 + n x O(n) x (1 + (O(n) x 2)) = O(n^3)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, the reason between a being log n and b being just n... would it be because of the K*C vs k+C OR because the second for loop is based off i